# returning a vector from function with int input

Tags: c++

I am doing an exercise where I'm trying to list Prime Numbers. Instead of simply listing them, I am trying to have them listed in a Vector(dynamic sizing).

I can't understand why I can't get them listed out.

```
#include "TestFile.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> primeCalc(int z)
{
    vector<int> myVector;

    for (int i = 3; i <= 100; i += 2)
    {
        float val = i; // Produce float value
        int mid = static_cast<int>(sqrt(val));
        int j;
        for (j = 3; j <= mid; j += 2)
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;

        if (j > mid)
            myVector.push_back(i);
    }
    cout << sizeof(myVector) << endl;
    return myVector;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 100;
    vector<int> myAnswer;

    myVector = primeCalc(x);
    for (std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = myAnswer.begin(); i != myAnswer.end(); i++) 
    {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Made edits based on suggestions. Got this error: no viable conversion from `'__wrap_iter<pointer>'` to `'__wrap_iter<const_pointer>'`. I too don't understand why `sizeof()` returned a value of 24 when I counted 48 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to manually print the contents of an `std::vector`; you can do this in `main()` or `primeCalc()`:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = myVector.begin(); i != myVector.end(); i++) {
    std::cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

If you want `primeCalc()` to return a vector, you'll need to change its return type from `int` to `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: If I change the return type from int to std::vector<int>, it means I'd have to initialise the function as a vector type too?

Comment: You don't really initialise functions in C++, are you talking about passing in an int to `primeCalc()`? If so, then you can keep that argument as is.

You would need to initialise an `std::vector<int>` variable in `primeCalc()`, add the prime numbers to it, then return that variable.

Comment: @RyanLee I've edited my answer to use `<int>` instead of `<char>`. This should fix at least one issue.

As for `sizeof(myVector)`, you should instead use `myVector.size()` to get the number of elements in `myVector`.